# Как выбрать рандомно строку из файла? Java

Tags: java

Код, показывающий весь список строк.
Нужно рандомно показывать только одну.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("movies.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line=scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
}
```

Comment: Считай все данные в ArrayList. Потом сгенерируй индекс, значение которого больше нуля и меньше длины объекта ArrayList. По этому индексу достань строку из того же объекта ArrayList. Все.

Answer (score 0):

Для java 1.7 и выше

```
List<String> result = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("movies.txt"));
System.out.println(result.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, result.size()-1)));
```